# Pull in taxonomy field of custom post type in new query

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop

I have a Custom Post Type named `companion`. Via Companion I create articles which are then associated with my custom taxonomy `issueCompanion`. Imagine issueCompanion as a publication which is released periodically, like a magazine. I have another custom Taxonomy called 'topic' which acts like categories, and is associated with each article in companion.

I display this on the front-end via `taxonomy-issueCompanion.php`. On this page, I have to display the topic of each article, next to each article. The articles are easy to pull in because they come with the regular wordpress loop (if have_posts(), while have_posts()), but I can't seem to get to the topic taxonomy of each displayed article.

How do I display each article's corresponding issue? In other words, how do I display a custom taxonomy (topic) on a custom post type's post (companion)? I feel like I've done this 100 times but it doesn't seem to work for me this time.

Thank you for any input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your loop on the `taxonomy-issueCompanion.php` template file you can retrieve the terms of the taxonomy that are attached to the post.

```
// Inside of your while loop 
$post_topics = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'topic');

// And then you can do as you wish with your topics!
```

Comment: I had this backwards... Thanks for setting my head straight, I need a break now.